# Feature scaling getting high Error Value (sum of squared)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, sums-of-squares

I got a test data set to work on in order to implement feature scaling and get better results with gradient descent.
It looks like this:

```
x_0   x_1   x_2    y

1.00  1.31  -2.26  3942934
1.00  -1.9  2.32   2384832
...   ...   ....   ...
```

---

If you are wondering why the x_0 feature is always 1, it's because as I use a multivariate gradient_descent algorithm, I can perform y = mx+b like m<sub>1</sub> * x<sub>1</sub> + m<sub>2</sub> * x<sub>2</sub> + b
Let's say b = m_0, as all x_0 are equal to 1, the equation would be m<sub>0</sub>*x<sub>0</sub> + m<sub>1</sub>*x<sub>1</sub> + m<sub>2</sub>*x<sub>2</sub> = m<sub>0</sub> + m<sub>1</sub>*x<sub>1</sub> + m<sub>2</sub>*x<sub>2</sub>

---

## Cost Function

The problem is when I am computing my cost function (sum of squared difference of real value and predicted value) on this feature scaled data_set, I start my m_values to 0's. So the difference of predicted and real value is really high, (as high as y values). So if I sum the square of these differences, I get an error value like 6x10<sup>10</sup>.

This is of course a wrong error value, and though minimizing the function works well, I get very high and unexpected m values.

My intuition tells me to also "feature" scale the outputs (here y), but if it's called feature scaling, I think it should be only applied on features.

Any help would be very appreciated.